# Is there a way to replace one user control with another user control based on index

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have created two user controls and I am planning to bind it inside a list view. In the main window I have a button and on the button click I am adding the first user control repeatedly. For that I created a observable collection of user controls and adding that to the list view. Currently that part is working well(On each button click first user control is adding to the list view properly). Now the requirement I have,

1. The list view can have usercontrol1 multiple time depends on the button click.
2. This user control have a button which will open usercontrol2.
3. Now the requirement I have, when I click the button from usercontrol1, user control one need to replace with usercontrol2. It is not about just replace, since the list view contain the usercontrol1 multiple times, if I click the nth usercontrol1, only that usercontrol1 need to replce with usercontrol2.

Since the description is bit confusing, I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q87Qm.jpg) am adding an image which shows the idea and the code part how I bind usercontrol1 to the list view multiple time.

```
public ObservableCollection<UserControl> lis = new ObservableCollection<UserControl>();

private void NextScreen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserCntrl1 usr = new UserCntrl1();
        ListView.ItemsSource = lis;
        lis.Add(usr);
    }
```

Comment: Please refer image

Answer (score 0):

Adding a collection of UserControls to the ItemsSource property is wrong in the first place.

You should instead declare the UserControls in the ControlTemplate of the ListBoxItem. Switch between different templates by DataTriggers on a property in the data item class, like `IsSelected` in the example below. On Button click, change that property on the appropriate item.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:UserControl1 .../>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <local:UserControl2 .../>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: But, this way am I able to add multiple user controls to the listview?

Comment: Sure, a UserControl instance will be created for every element of the Items collection, and the individual item will automatically be passed to the DataContext of the UserControl. Take a look at [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is using a `TabControl` with Collapsed `TabItem`s and a navigation trigger via a `Button`. You can then easily place your page controls within each `TabItem`.

```xml
<Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="MainTabControl">
        <TabItem Header="Page1" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="Page 1"/>
                <Button Content="Next" Click="Page1_Button_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Page2" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Label Content="Page 2"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

When the user clicks on the button the desired tab index is selected.

```cs
private void Page1_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainTabControl.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```